# Loading DLL in Enclave fails with ERROR_INVALID_IMAGE_HASH

Tags: windows, winapi, hyper-v, windows-dev-center

On Windows 10 64-bit Build 1809 with VBS enabled, kernelbase.LoadEnclaveImageA()  on a VBS enclave fails with error code ERROR_INVALID_IMAGE_HASH (0x241). The DLL being loaded is built with the linker flag /integritycheck and is signed with a test signing certificate using SignTool. The system on which this is being attempted has the BCD TestSigning ON. What other steps are required to load a DLL into a VBS enclave?
//KernelDev

Comment: This question is about  Win32 API programming i.e. conditions for calling the API LoadEnclaveImage() successfully.

Comment: Could you add some code on how exactly you create the enclave? Did you tried to call IsEnclaveTypeSupported() on the enclave type? is the enclave type a VBS enclave type?

Comment: The enclave is a VBS enclave and IsEnclaveTypeSupported(ENCLAVE_TYPE_VBS) returns TRUE. The call sequence is OpenProcess(), CreateEnclave(ENCLAVE_TYPE_VBS), LoadEnclaveImage(). The Enclave size is 4MB.